# Have any chemical reactions been used to simulate CTMC for economic simulations

Tags: interdisciplinary, markov-chain

### Assumption and Question

Given that many economic models can be viewed as [Continuous Time Markov Chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain), and that many [chemical reactions are also described as such](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain#Chemical_reactions), have any experiments been conducted comparing a queuing model (for example) with an enzyme-mediated reaction?

### Inference

If physical systems could be found that predictably react in a way that can be meaningfully correlated with models, could enzymes (or other physical inputs) be swapped (in a manner akin to tweaking variables), to allow for multiple simulations to be run simultaneously, especially with large sample sizes (given the order of magnitude of [Avogadro's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant))?

Has this been tried, and is anyone publishing on such systems?

Comment: I think this question is difficult to answer because people need to know of an example of it occuring. It is safe to say that for everyone who has viewed the question, the answer is "not to my knowledge". For that reason it may be a bad question. Although, I really am interested in whether work like this has been done. My guess is it hasn't though.